# What are the rights of Hermaphrodites in Islam?

Tags: sex, human-rights

[Hermaphrodite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermaphrodite) called Hijra in Pakistan/india and google tells me its

#### **خنثى**

in arabic,

- Want to know what Quran and Prophet(SAW) said about them and what are their rights ?
- Do they deserve equal rights and respect? or anything mentioned in
  Islam about them?
- What Islamic Laws of Inheritance says about them ?

I have seen those people in miserable situation, It seems society doesn't seems to own them 
I'd appreciate answers with good reference. 

**جزاك اللهُ**

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the view of islam about transgender people?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8664/what-is-the-view-of-islam-about-transgender-people)

Comment: No, thats not the exact question i am asking i am asking about their rights in society and about their livings and acceptance in society, the question you think is duplicate is asking something else

Comment: @Muslim well maybe but the answer there is unsatisfactory to me. As i once held a book in may hands where the inheritance issue was discussed, which apparently wasn't part of your Question!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a lot about your question but I know in some countries like Iran, transsexuals are allowed (by the law and religion) to perform surgery operations to change their sex. So they will have one fixed sex in their life.

This link is about one of these people:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maryam_Khatoon_Molkara

And based on the wikipedia article about [Hijra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hijra_%28South_Asia%29) some of them are ordinary men which are joined these groups when they've been young.