# Transgender in Islam

Tags: homosexuality, transgender

My research suggests that trans is someone who switches their gender at some point in there life. And my question is that what does Islam have to say regarding these people? How should a trans be dealt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is transgender haram in islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45200/is-transgender-haram-in-islam)

Comment: Yeap. This help. Thanks alot!