# How do I cleanse my sin if I'm a transsexual woman?

Tags: sin, transgender

I am a transsexual woman and I am getting bullied for being transsexual by other Muslims.  But Islam is a religion I love and cherish, and I always loved reading the Quran in my free time.  A few days ago, I finally decided to start praying.

I cant stop being transsexual as i was diagnosed with a mental illness and take pills because I can't be happy in male body. How can I carry on living a pure Muslim life while being transsexual?

I do not hate Allah for being like this; it is not his fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scholarly attitudes on transgender people involve a [difference of opinion](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33444/17163) and [seem to be evolving](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/47190/17163).  While traditionally being transgender is considered haram, some modern scholars do not consider being transgender as haram, instead treating it more along the lines of a medical condition.

The trangender female narrative tends to follow the lines that Allah made this person innately female, and there was a biological mismatch at birth.  With this interpretation, hadith such as

> The Prophet cursed effeminate men (those men who are in the similitude (assume the manners of women) and those women who assume the manners of men
>   <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 5886](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/103)</sub>

imply that it's haram for a transgender female (who genuinely believes herself to be innately female) to impersonate a man.

The other argument main against transgender people is it's changing the creation of Allah ([Qur'an 4:119](https://quran.com/4/119)), but from a transgender person's perspective, it can be considered as correcting a biological defect (which is permissible in Islam).

So there are respectable justifications one might not even consider it a sin.

Answer (score 0):

1) Pray Allah to help you.
2) Believe in the Allah's mercy.
3) Resist temptation, Allah loves patient people and greatly reward them.
    Verily, with every difficulty there is relief (Quran, chapter Ash-Sharh).